# Using ezplot with specified ordinate range

Tags: matlab

I have a symbolic function that I am plotting with ezplot:

```
  ezplot(f, [0,1]);
```

I could not find a way to specify the y-values (ordniate) to plot this function. However, I want f to be plotted for x in [0,1] and y in [0,1] also. Default ezplot plots my function for y in [0,20] or something like that. How can I specify the y-range?

Here is my function (in q):

```
 ((490*q^3 - 1300*q^2 + 1080*q - 240)^2/(9*(240*q - 300*q^2 + 90*q^3)^2) - (655*q^3 - 1570*q^2 + 1160*q - 240)/(3*(90*q^3 - 300*q^2 + 240*q)))/((10*q^2 - 7*q^3)/(480*q - 600*q^2 + 180*q^3) - (1080*q - 1300*q^2 + 490*q^3 - 240)^3/(27*(240*q - 300*q^2 + 90*q^3)^3) + (((10*q^2 - 7*q^3)/(480*q - 600*q^2 + 180*q^3) - (1080*q - 1300*q^2 + 490*q^3 - 240)^3/(27*(240*q - 300*q^2 + 90*q^3)^3) + ((1080*q - 1300*q^2 + 490*q^3 - 240)*(1160*q - 1570*q^2 + 655*q^3 - 240))/(6*(240*q - 300*q^2 + 90*q^3)^2))^2 - ((1080*q - 1300*q^2 + 490*q^3 - 240)^2/(9*(240*q - 300*q^2 + 90*q^3)^2) - (1160*q - 1570*q^2 + 655*q^3 - 240)/(720*q - 900*q^2 + 270*q^3))^3)^(1/2) + ((1080*q - 1300*q^2 + 490*q^3 - 240)*(1160*q - 1570*q^2 + 655*q^3 - 240))/(6*(240*q - 300*q^2 + 90*q^3)^2))^(1/3) - (490*q^3 - 1300*q^2 + 1080*q - 240)/(3*(90*q^3 - 300*q^2 + 240*q)) + ((10*q^2 - 7*q^3)/(2*(90*q^3 - 300*q^2 + 240*q)) - (490*q^3 - 1300*q^2 + 1080*q - 240)^3/(27*(240*q - 300*q^2 + 90*q^3)^3) + (((10*q^2 - 7*q^3)/(2*(90*q^3 - 300*q^2 + 240*q)) - (490*q^3 - 1300*q^2 + 1080*q - 240)^3/(27*(240*q - 300*q^2 + 90*q^3)^3) + ((490*q^3 - 1300*q^2 + 1080*q - 240)*(655*q^3 - 1570*q^2 + 1160*q - 240))/(6*(240*q - 300*q^2 + 90*q^3)^2))^2 - ((490*q^3 - 1300*q^2 + 1080*q - 240)^2/(9*(240*q - 300*q^2 + 90*q^3)^2) - (655*q^3 - 1570*q^2 + 1160*q - 240)/(3*(90*q^3 - 300*q^2 + 240*q)))^3)^(1/2) + ((490*q^3 - 1300*q^2 + 1080*q - 240)*(655*q^3 - 1570*q^2 + 1160*q - 240))/(6*(240*q - 300*q^2 + 90*q^3)^2))^(1/3)
```

Comment: could you give an example of the 'f' function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function of `q` as written in a string can be evaluated using `ezplot`, but you will have a much better control of the plot properties using the `plot` function. You can set the `Xlim` and `YLim` properties for example.

Here is a piece of code

```
%evaluate function and plot
f = ' ((490*q^3 - 1300*q^2 + 1080*q - 240)^2/(9*(240*q - 300*q^2 + 90*q^3)^2) - (655*q^3 - 1570*q^2 + 1160*q - 240)/(3*(90*q^3 - 300*q^2 + 240*q)))/((10*q^2 - 7*q^3)/(480*q - 600*q^2 + 180*q^3) - (1080*q - 1300*q^2 + 490*q^3 - 240)^3/(27*(240*q - 300*q^2 + 90*q^3)^3) + (((10*q^2 - 7*q^3)/(480*q - 600*q^2 + 180*q^3) - (1080*q - 1300*q^2 + 490*q^3 - 240)^3/(27*(240*q - 300*q^2 + 90*q^3)^3) + ((1080*q - 1300*q^2 + 490*q^3 - 240)*(1160*q - 1570*q^2 + 655*q^3 - 240))/(6*(240*q - 300*q^2 + 90*q^3)^2))^2 - ((1080*q - 1300*q^2 + 490*q^3 - 240)^2/(9*(240*q - 300*q^2 + 90*q^3)^2) - (1160*q - 1570*q^2 + 655*q^3 - 240)/(720*q - 900*q^2 + 270*q^3))^3)^(1/2) + ((1080*q - 1300*q^2 + 490*q^3 - 240)*(1160*q - 1570*q^2 + 655*q^3 - 240))/(6*(240*q - 300*q^2 + 90*q^3)^2))^(1/3) - (490*q^3 - 1300*q^2 + 1080*q - 240)/(3*(90*q^3 - 300*q^2 + 240*q)) + ((10*q^2 - 7*q^3)/(2*(90*q^3 - 300*q^2 + 240*q)) - (490*q^3 - 1300*q^2 + 1080*q - 240)^3/(27*(240*q - 300*q^2 + 90*q^3)^3) + (((10*q^2 - 7*q^3)/(2*(90*q^3 - 300*q^2 + 240*q)) - (490*q^3 - 1300*q^2 + 1080*q - 240)^3/(27*(240*q - 300*q^2 + 90*q^3)^3) + ((490*q^3 - 1300*q^2 + 1080*q - 240)*(655*q^3 - 1570*q^2 + 1160*q - 240))/(6*(240*q - 300*q^2 + 90*q^3)^2))^2 - ((490*q^3 - 1300*q^2 + 1080*q - 240)^2/(9*(240*q - 300*q^2 + 90*q^3)^2) - (655*q^3 - 1570*q^2 + 1160*q - 240)/(3*(90*q^3 - 300*q^2 + 240*q)))^3)^(1/2) + ((490*q^3 - 1300*q^2 + 1080*q - 240)*(655*q^3 - 1570*q^2 + 1160*q - 240))/(6*(240*q - 300*q^2 + 90*q^3)^2))^(1/3)';
h=ezplot(f,[0 1]);

%get X and Y data
X = get(h,'XData');
Y = get(h,'YData');

%plot X and Y over the ezplot
plot(X,Y)
set(gca, 'XLim', [0 1], 'YLim', [0 2.5]);
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezplot.html):

> ```
> ezplot(fun2,[xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax])
> ```

So I'm guessing in your case it's simply

```
ezplot(f, [0,1,0,1])
```

But that assumes `f` is an implicit function. So you must write it as such. For example writing the explicit function `f = @(x) x` as an implicit function and plotting it between 0 and 1:

```
f = @(x,y) y - x;
ezplot(f, [0,1,0,1])
```

So basically just rewrite it as `y` - whatever you had before assuming your `f` was explicit. If it was implicit then you can literally just specify the y-axis limits.

For your example writing the explicit function in your comment as an implicit function:

```
f = @(x,y) = y - (x^2-x^(3/2)+...)
```

Comment: That exactly is the problem: My function f is a very HUGE complicated function which I get as input from somewhere else. Its form is f(x)=x^2-x^(3/2)+... I was hoping that I don't have to manipulate that huge function but just plot it as is.

Comment: @tw-S It is very easy to manipulate though, it's just `f(x,y) will equal `y` - `f(x)`, but you must copy and paste your `x^2-...` instead of `f(x)`

Comment: Ok, if I copy and paste the expression like you said, the plot is empty and I get this warning: Warning: Function failed to evaluate on array inputs; vectorizing the function may speed up its evaluation and avoid the need to
loop over array elements.

Comment: @tw-S I guess you'd better post your function then

Comment: The warning is suggesting that you change all you `*`, `^` and `/` etc to `.*`, `.^` and `./`. I suggest you do it using sting handling functions. BTW you get the same warning when you try `ezplot` that explicitly